# calculate moments of an image

Tags: opencv

i Have 2d images that i converted to RGB format , calculated the threshold , the contours and the moments and i didn't know how to calculate all the lines of contour

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want to get (mark it by hand in paint or something)? Also can you post a picture of the tumor without the markings and please post the code as code (use triple bacticks ``` at the top and bottom for a code block).

Comment: thanks for answering me , i want to calculate and draw all the axis that pass through the centroide in order to plot it in a histogram  but i did not know how to do it

Comment: you drew four axes. why is it four, and why are they lying the way they are? what "is" an axis through that tumor? how is it defined?

Comment: the point of view of the doctor consist of calculating all the axis (not just four it's just an example) that pass through the center of mass because through  this calculation he will have an idea of the length of these axis and so the geometric complexity of the tumor

Answer (score 1):

You can get the lines by drawing from a contour point through the centroid. If you go through all of the contour points you'll get all of the lines about twice.

[image]

Histogram of lengths (in pixels)

[image]

```py
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# returns 2d distance
def dist2D(p1, p2):
    dx = p1[0] - p2[0];
    dy = p1[1] - p2[1];
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

# returns length of long side
def getLongSide(box_points):
    # unpack
    a,b,c,_ = box_points;

    # look for longest
    ab = dist2D(a, b);
    bc = dist2D(b, c);
    return max(ab, bc);

# returns the biggest contour
def getBiggestContour(contours):
    biggest = None;
    big_size = -1;
    for con in contours:
        perim = cv2.arcLength(con, True);
        if perim > big_size:
            biggest = con;
            big_size = perim;
    return biggest;

# make lines
def getLine(point, center, mask):
    # get vector of line
    dx = center[0] - point[0];
    dy = center[1] - point[1];

    # stretch at least through the tumor
    dx *= 10;
    dy *= 10; # as the centroid this should be enough

    # translate to point
    dx += point[0];
    dy += point[1];
    second_point = (int(dx), int(dy));

    # draw on blank
    blank = np.zeros_like(mask);
    tup = (int(point[0]), int(point[1]));
    cv2.line(blank, tup, second_point, (255), 1);

    # mask
    blank = cv2.bitwise_and(blank, mask);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("blank", blank);
    cv2.waitKey(1);
    return blank;

# load image
img = cv2.imread("tumor.png");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# mask
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 100, 255);

# dilate out the small holes
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8);
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 1);
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations = 1);

# contours
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# get biggest contour
biggest = getBiggestContour(contours);
cv2.drawContours(img, [biggest], -1, (0, 200, 0), 2);

# create a new mask
mask = np.zeros_like(mask);
cv2.drawContours(mask, [biggest], -1, (255), -1);

# center
M = cv2.moments(biggest);
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']);
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00']);
center = (int(cx), int(cy));

# draw
img = cv2.circle(img, center, 2, (0,0,200), -1);

# draw lines (get over drawn by second half)
color = 0;
sign = 1;
lengths = [];
for point in biggest:
    # get mask
    point = point[0]; # contours have an extra set of brackets
    line_mask = getLine(point, center, mask);

    # get minRect and take long side to get line
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(line_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    biggest = getBiggestContour(contours);
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(biggest);
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect);
    
    # get line length
    length = getLongSide(box);
    lengths.append(length);
    print(length);

    # draw mask
    img[line_mask == 255] = (color, color, 0);
    color += sign;

    # check sign
    if color >= 255:
        sign = -1;
    if color <= 0:
        sign = 1;

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=lengths, bins='auto', color='#0504aa', alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85)
plt.show();

# show
cv2.imshow("Tumor", img);
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: i want to know what did you want to do by # stretch at least through the tumor , # translate to point

Comment: center - point gives me the vector from point -> center. I want to stretch it (i.e. multiply it) at least far enough so that it is bigger than the length of the tumor because I need to draw the line past the opposite edge. I then have to translate it because I want to draw this line starting from the point, not the origin (0,0).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for. Do you mean can you run this on each scan slice of the tumor and reconstruct it in 3D? You may want to ask this as a separate question, it sounds non-trivial.

Comment: The same basic idea for this (find points on the surface and draw lines through the centroid) should extend to 3D as well. The vector math should even be roughly the same. You'll have to come up with some other way of detecting when the line crosses the other side, but the rest should more or less work.

Comment: what i want is a 3d image with lines pass through the centroid of this 3d image.Is it feasible ?? and i want to know if there is another way to do the whole calculation with all the slices of the scan grouped in one 3d array

Comment: If you know the distance (change in depth) between each scan then this should be doable. You can reconstruct the 3D surface by layering the contour points of each scan.

Comment: yes. You use the contours of each scan to create your 3d surface. Then you draw lines from each of those contour points through the 3d centroid of your image.

Comment: yes i have the slice thickness but i'm not sure what you want to say about layering the contour points of each scan and how to calculate it with slice thickness

Comment: The contour points give you (x,y). The slice elevation gives you (z)